# Using Ajax to automate Like button with refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to add Ajax to my like button to avoid refreshing everytime along with updating the count automatically as well but it is not working properly and the page keeps refreshing for some reason:

So when I was trying to debug my code in Google Chrome Console Log I keep receving this error:
`127.0.0.1/:96 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gannpgaobkkhmpomoijebaigcapoeebl/bundle.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` for some reason. I am not an expert in JS but I am trying to understand what is happening here.

So my template for the like button here it is:

```
      <form action="{% url 'blog:like-post' %}" method="POST" class="like-form" id="{{post.id}}">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value='{{post.id}}'>

        <button type="submit" class="like-btn{{post.id}}">

        {% if user not in post.liked.all %}

          Like

        {% else %}

          Unlike

        {% endif %}

        </button>

        <div class="like-count{{post.id}}">{{ post.num_likes }} Likes</div>
      </form>
```

Here is the Script

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            let display = false

            $('.like-form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault()

                const post_id = $(this).attr('id')

                const likeText = $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text()
                const trim = $.trim(likeText)

                const url = $(this).attr('action')

                let res;
                const likes = $(`.like-count${post_id}`).text()
                const trimCount = parseInt(likes)

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                        'post_id':post_id,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(trim === 'Unlike') {
                            $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text('Like')
                            res = trimCount - 1
                        } else {
                            $(`.like-btn${post_id}`).text('Unlike')
                            res = trimCount + 1
                        }

                        $(`.like-count${post_id}`).text(res)
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.log('error', response)
                    }
                })

            })
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: did you include jquery if you are using it as error states  $ is not defined

Comment: @iklinac yes I added in the base html     `<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: this source is likely to be not found by your browser look further into
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: @iklinac is this the only reason it is not showing?